# Resgatar o maior número de uma matriz com critérios

Tags: microsoft-excel

Preciso de alguma fórmula ou lógica para resgatar o maior número de uma matriz, porém com determinados critérios.

Assim como as fórmulas CONT.SES e SOMASES que conta e soma os números de uma matriz quando os critérios são 'atendidos'.

Algo que funcionaria como um `MAIOR.SES(IntervaloApuração;K;IntervaloCriterio1;Criterio1;...)`

Um exemplo simples de como funcionaria:

```
+---+-------+-------+------------+
|   |   A   |   B   |     C      |
+---+-------+-------+------------+
| 1 | Data  | Ativo | Quantidade |
| 2 | 26/07 | SIM   | 35         |
| 3 | 26/07 | SIM   | 39         |
| 4 | 26/07 | NAO   | 40         |
| 5 | 27/07 | SIM   | 13         |
+---+-------+-------+------------+
```

Caso eu quiser a maior quantidade dos seguintes critérios: `data = 26/07` e `Ativo = SIM` o resultado iria me retornar a quantidade do registro 3 ou seja: `39`

Alguém com uma solução?

Comment: Poderia criar um exemplo de uma matriz e o que espera como resultado?

Comment: Math, editei o post com o exemplo.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use a função "MÁXIMO" e dentro dela use o "SE". Entretanto, você deverá ficar atento que a fórmula desse jeito funciona para uma única célula, para o seu caso é necessário fazer com que ela funcione com vetores, e para isso que existe uma ferramente no Excel que se chama [Array Formulas](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/arrayformulas.aspx).

Para usá-la, é tão simples quanto apertar três teclas. Ao invés de apertar <kbd>Enter</kbd>, você pressionará <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Para ter certeza se deu certo ou não, verifique se a fórmula ficou com um par de chaves antes e depois dela, assim: `{=MÁXIMO(SE(A2:A6=F2;(SE(B2:B6=F3;C2:C6))))}`.

Para o seu caso, ficaria assim:

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Resultado:

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas não se esqueça do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> ao digitar a fórmula na célula F6.

Comment: Show de bola! também foi possível usar o MAIOR que dá até pra resgatar o segundo maior, teceiro maior e etc..

Answer (score 0):

Mais simples ainda, basta utilizar a fórmula MÁXIMOSES, que faz exatamente o que deseja:

```
MÁXIMOSES(IntervaloApuração;IntervaloCriterio1;Criterio1;...)
```